# Can anyone explain me that why else is running even I got the number that I want to search from array

Tags: java, data-structures

Here I am searching for a number say 4, Although it is presented in my array num[] but still not founded by using if condition . If I remove else condition it is prints founded..quite confusing for me that why this happening.

```
int n=0;
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
int num[]={1,2,3,4,5};
System.out.print("Enter Number To Search");
n=sc.nextInt();
for(int i=1;i<=num.length;i++)
{
    if(n==num[i])
    {        
        System.out.println("Founded !");       
        break;       
    }
    else 
    {        
        System.out.println("Not Found !");
        break;        
    }

}
```

Comment: Remove the break condition in the else. If the first element of the array doesnt match to the number you inserted, you are not checking the rest of the numbers in the array.

Comment: It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

It is because after the first iteration when you your number did not match, you are breaking the loop without further searching for the number. Delete your breaks and it will work

Answer (score 0):

1. Your condition is wrong in else part check it remove **`break`** statement from else part
2. The **`break`** statement in your else part will terminate the loop if your value is not match with input number and not check further  value in `array`

Try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
     if (n == num[i]) {
           System.out.println("Founded !");
           break;

      } else {
            System.out.println("Not Found !");

      }       
}
```

OR this

```
for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
         if (n == num[i]) {
               System.out.println("Founded !");
               break;

          } else {
                continue;

          }       
    }
```

OR THIS

```
 boolean flag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            if (n == num[i]) {
                flag=true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(flag){
            System.out.println("Founded !");
        }else {
            System.out.println("Not Found !");
        }
```

Comment: run:
Enter Number To Search5
Not Found !
Not Found !
Not Found !
Not Found !
Founded !
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

Comment: Enter Number To Search 34
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
 at dsa.array.main(array.java:126)
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

Comment: Enter Number To Search 6
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
 at dsa.array.main(array.java:127)
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

Comment: @AkshayRohilla check this `for (int i = 1; i <= num.length; i++)`

Comment: Enter Number To Search 39
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
 at dsa.array.main(array.java:127)
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

Comment: Did you test your code ? remove the = from the testing part of the code it should only be < to avoid array index bound issues

Comment: @nits.kk **yes**

Comment: make <= to < to avoid ArrayIndexOutofBoundException

Comment: @nits.kk silly mistake mistke while copy paste thamks

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `break` when number not found. That's why the loop is stopped before it reaches the expected number. Remove `break` from else.

**Alert!** You are iterating your loop upto `num.length` and using num[i]. That means if you may get **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**, when `i = num.length`. So, you should use either `i < num.length` or `num[i-1]`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    if(n == num[i]) {        
        System.out.println("Founded !");       
        break;       
    }
    if(i == num.length -1) {        
        System.out.println("Not Found !");      
    }

}
```

In another way,

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    if(n == num[i]) {             
        break;       
    }       
}
if(i < num.length)
    System.out.println("Founded !"); 
else
    System.out.println("Not Found !");
```

Comment: run:
Enter Number To Search5
Not Found !
Not Found !
Not Found !
Not Found !
Founded !
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

Comment: What is your expected output? Just "Founded" when number is found, otherwise "Not Found"?

Comment: yeah..but it is showing 4 times not found and then founded

Comment: Of course there are many many ways to do it. You can set a flag and check outside the loop. I just saved the tiny memory. :)

Comment: @AkshayRohilla another suggestion, the word is not 'founded', it's 'found'.

Comment: its not about spelling ..Grow up

Answer (score 0):

You first need to run through the entire forloop and see if the number is present. if the entire loop finishes and you have still not found the number, then you can say it is not found in the array. Look at the below code,

```
int n=0;
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
int num[]={1,2,3,4,5};
System.out.print("Enter Number To Search");
n=sc.nextInt();
boolean foundFlag = false;
for(int i=0;i<=num.length;i++){
   if(n==num[i]){
      foundFlag = true;
      System.out.println("Founded !");
      break;
   }
 }
 if(!foundFlag){
 System.out.println("Not Found !");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us analyze the step of the program run, when code run to (1), the method blocked,you input 4,and code continue run,code run to for circulation,the first circulation,i=1,num[1]=2,but n=4, so code run to the else branch,and break,exist.

If we take out the else branch,when code doesn't run to if branch in the circulation, it won't break , it will run to next circulation.
  When it run to Third circulation,this moment i=3,n=4,num[3]=4,reach the if condition,then print "Founded !".

```
        int n=0;
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        int num[]={1,2,3,4,5};
        System.out.print("Enter Number To Search");
        n=sc.nextInt();//(1)
        for(int i=1;i<=num.length;i++)
        {
            if(n==num[i])
            {
                System.out.println("Founded !");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Not Found !");
                break;
            }

        }
```